# Rails - Geocoder - .near wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 0..1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I'm having a slight issue trying to get nearest locations of a workers. In my controller I have this:

```
Worker.near(self.coordinates.reverse, radius, {:unit => :miles, :order => :distance})
```

self.coordinates.reverse contains => [43.0712, -76.1105]

radius : 20

I am getting below error:

wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 0..1)

**Gem-file contains:**

```
ruby "2.3.1"
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.6'
gem 'geocoder'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be :

```
Worker.near('self.coordinates.reverse, radius, {:unit => :miles, :order => :distance}')
```

or

```
Worker.near("self.coordinates.reverse, radius, {:unit => :miles, :order => :distance}")
```